# How to stop unattended-upgrades from upgrading my custom installed Debian packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

I've custom compiled my own version of ffmpeg and made a .deb file from this package. The package is described as follows

`control.txt`

```
Package: ffmpeg
Version: 4.3-ubuntu1804+hwaccel.cuda+20200806
Architecture: amd64
Depends: ${insert dependencies here}
Replaces: ffmpeg, libavutil-dev, libavformat-dev, libavcodec-dev, libswresample-dev, libavdevice-dev, libavfilter-dev, libavresample-dev, libpostproc-dev, libswscale-dev, libmp3lame0
Maintainer: me@me.com
Description: some ffmpeg package I built with CUDA hwaccel for Ubuntu 1804 targets
```

I then take my system, an Ubuntu 18.04 server device, that already has `ffmpeg` installed from the system repositories and run the following

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y ./ffmpeg_4.3-ubuntu1804+hwaccel.cuda+20200806_amd64.deb
```

and it installs ffmpeg into my system and **replaces the one that was already installed**. I let this run for a while and when I come back I notice that the `ffmpeg` installed on my system is the one from the Ubuntu repositories. Namely, version `7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2`.

I go to check the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file and see this

```
Upgrade: ffmpeg:amd64 (4.3-ubuntu1804+hwaccel.cuda+20200919, 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2)
End-Date: 2020-09-20  06:04:48
```

It looks like it noticed my custom compiled version of ffmpeg on the system and did some sort of version comparison to the one in the repositories and noticed that it was behind that one and did an automatic upgrade. The issue is, mine **is not** behind the one in the repositories (4.3 vs 3.4.8) and also that, I installed this custom-compiled version myself, why does unattended-upgrades go ahead and undo my work by installing the default one from the repositories?

My question is - how do I tell `unattended-upgrades` to not, under any circumstance, touch this package, and better yet, how to tell it to not touch any packages that I install from custom compiled .deb files?

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI in case anyone comes across this answer in the future, there are three things you can do.

1. Uninstall `unattended-upgrades`
2. Change the line `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` to have the line `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";` instead of `1`
3. Mark a "hold" on the package in question. So `sudo apt-mark hold ffmpeg`. This tells apt-get and other programs to not upgrade this package.

Comment: I wanted it to just not automatically do it, but rather that I manually upgrade from repositories. Using `apt-mark unhold $pkg; apt install --only-upgrade $pkg; apt-mark hold $pkg`, thanks for the hint! Note that you can accept your own answer btw