# How to enable / disable Linux unattended-upgrades non-interactively

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, auto-update, dpkg

My requirement is to enable/disable the `unattended-upgrades` in Ubuntu all through non-interactively.

What I know is that we do have solutions like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470709/how-do-i-stop-disable-unattended-upgrades-from-being-launched-automatically) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006292/how-to-stop-unattended-upgrades-from-upgrading-my-custom-installed-debian-packag) but all of them suggests the same manual changes which I don't want.

So basically the command `dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` would prompt you an interactive window to select either `Yes` or `No` and I want to bypass this.

[image]

And I would only prefer these trivial solutions as my last resort if we don't have any better ways of doing this -

1. Uninstall `unattended-upgrades`
2. Make string replacements in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` to have the line
   `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";` instead of `1`. And this may also require some kind of reload which I am not sure about.

> Someone new to this topic and is curious what this is all about, you
> may refer
> [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/automatic-security-updates-ubuntu)
> link.

Comment: Why don't you just stop and disable the service?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes, I think it could also be one of the better options, btw do you what's its equivalent service?

Comment: Try systemctl list-unit-files | grep unattended

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thaks! I got the exact service name and I was also able to stop and disable that, however, looks like the critical security updates were still picked up, this is strange. If not this service, then who did that?  I am investigating more into this.